How do I add a reference to IBM.Data.DB2 in the .nuspec file?
I'm bulding a local NuGet package which connects to an IBM DB2 instance using Framework 4.8.
I am required to use the provided version of the DB2 driver provided with the IBM installation.
I would like the installation of my NuGet package to automatically add a reference to the user's local copy of IBM.Data.DB2 but set to CopyLocal=false within Visual Studio.  None of the other posts I've seen seem to deal with this specific scenario.
Here's what I've tried:
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>author</authors>
    <owners>owner</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>SQL Helper</description>
    <releaseNotes>Supports Oracle, DB2.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018, 2024</copyright>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="23.4.0" />
    </dependencies>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\netf40\IBM.Data.DB2.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="false" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
      <files>
          <file src="C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\netf40\IBM.Data.DB2.dll" target="lib\net40"/>
     </files>
</package>

Suggestions appreciated.  Thanks!
